# In Hibernate, do we need 3 tables to accomplish many to many relationship?

Tags: hibernate

Do we need 3 tables to accomplish many to many relationship in hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

In systems analysis, a many-to-many relationship is a type of cardinality that refers to the relationship between two entities (see also Entity-Relationship Model) A and B in which A may contain a parent row for which there are many children in B and vice versa. For instance, think of A as Authors, and B as Books. An Author can write several Books, and a Book can be written by several Authors. Because most database management systems only support one-to-many relationships, it is necessary to implement such relationships physically via a third junction table (cross-reference table), say, AB with two one-to-many relationships A -> AB and B -> AB. In this case the logical primary key for AB is formed from the two foreign keys (i.e. copies of the primary keys of A and B).

You can have more as well if you want, but 3 is the minimum

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It will be helpful if  you share any examples or links.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more to do with the nature of many-to-many relationships that hibernate itself. Yes, as G-Man correctly pointed out, you need 3 tables (or more) to implement it.

Take a look at hibernate's documentation on [association mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m2m), especially the section [7.5.3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-m2m)

Here's an example taken from the same doc:

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="addresses" table="PersonAddress">
        <key column="personId"/>
        <many-to-many column="addressId"
            class="Address"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="people" inverse="true" table="PersonAddress">
        <key column="addressId"/>
        <many-to-many column="personId"
            class="Person"/>
    </set>
</class>
```